# Django difficulty in displaying the data(count)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-shell

Im new to django and trying to learn with building a forum

my model

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=128)
    created=models.DateTimeField('Created Date')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Book(models.Model):
    book_subject=models.ForeignKey(Subject,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    book_title=models.CharField(max_length=128)
    url=models.URLField()
    votes=models.IntegerField(default=0)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.book_title
```

my query to database in django shell

```
Subject.objects.all()
>>>[<Subject: electronics>, <Subject: compter science>]

q=Subject.objects.get(id=2)
q.book_set.all()
>>>[<Book: python django>, <Book: python flask>]
```

How should i get the number of books for each subjects. (to get **count of books** for **electronics and computer science subjects**) I know this could be straight forward answer. I wanted to show the template as in forum where it displays subject name and number of books it contains

Can someone help me with query to get **number of books for each subjects**

Any help is much appreciated..Thanks in advance

Comment: Please choose a more appropriate title for your question. Your issue isn't in displaying data, but in calculating counts.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman...have done the changes

Answer (score 3):

If you only need the number of books for a certain subject, there is [`count`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#count)

```
Subject.objects.get(id=2).book_set.count()
```

If you need the subjects with a count for the number of books for them you can [`annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#annotate)

```
from django.db.models import Count
subjects = Subject.objects.annotate(num_books=Count('book'))

for subj in subjects:
    print subj.num_books
```

Comment: @Sayse..Im getting error "FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'books' into field. Choices are: book, created, id, name"

Comment: @AmoghAngadi - It should be `book`

Comment: @AmoghAngadi - No worries, theres a link in my answer to the documentation for it

Comment: @Sayse..How i can get the count of number of books separately for electronics and computer science?

Comment: @Sayse..your answer doesn't give separate count of 2 books.....help me please..... to get count of books for electronics and computer science

Comment: @AmoghAngadi - You've updated your question to be a different question, this answer does solve your original question, if you have another question then you should raise it as a separate question (with what you have tried/researched)

Comment: @Sayse......I actually meant the same...but made changes to make things clear mate

Comment: @spidy This answer should give you what you want. If you want it in one object, try this: `Subject.objects.annotate(num_books=Count('book')).values('name', 'num_books')`