# django NOT NULL constraint failed: app_subject.created

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Im getting null constraint when I'm trying to save the form

My model

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=128,  blank=True)
    created=models.DateTimeField('Created Date',blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Book(models.Model):
    book_subject=models.ForeignKey(Subject,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    book_name=models.CharField(max_length=128)
    url=models.URLField()
    votes=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    created_time=models.DateTimeField('Created Date',blank=True)
    comments=models.CharField(max_length=400)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.book_name
```

my forms

```
class SubjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Subject
        fields=('name', )

class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields=('book_title',)
```

views.py

```
def add_subject(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SubjectForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return index(request)
        else:
            print form.errors
    else:
        form = SubjectForm()
    return render(request,'add_subj.html', {'form': form})
```

Im getting null constraint error when saving the form. Error is caused in views.py at  **form.save(commit=True)** ...everything is straight forward..but confusing.....What could be the problem...

when I print the form I get following answer

```
<tr><th><label for="id_name">Name:</label></th><td><input id="id_name" maxlength="128" name="name" type="text" value="civil" /></td></tr>
```

Any help is much appreciated...thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're not actually setting the "created" field, and while you've set `blank=True`, you haven't set `null=True`. `blank` just means that the field doesn't need to be filled in forms, while `null` actually allows the fields to be `None` in the database. This is why your form is validating, but not actually saving.

So, you could add `null=True` to your `created` and `created_time` fields. However, if your intention is just to have them store the created date, it would be easier to just make the fields something like:

```
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

[`auto_now_add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) will automatically set the field for you on the object's creation. This should pretty much do what you need.

Comment: could you please help me with my other question ....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35357279/django-difficulty-in-displaying-the-datacount